JDBC + Postgres - Prevent JDBC from adding casts on parameter values
Postgres JDBC driver by default replaces variable values ​​with strings, adding a "cast" to the appropriate type.
public void test() throws Exception {
    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("user", POSTGRES_USER);
    props.setProperty("password", POSTGRES_PASS);

    try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(POSTGRES_URL, props);
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("select * from zzz_teste where zzz_cod in (?, ?)")) {
        ps.setBigDecimal(1, BigDecimal.ONE); // I used BigDecimal only for demonstration
        ps.setInt(2, 2);
        System.out.println(ps.toString());
    }
}

Result:
select * from zzz_teste where zzz_cod in (('1'::numeric), ('2'::int4))

This conversion is negatively impacting the performance of some SQL statements.
Is it possible to configure so that the value is sent with the appropriate type, without the "cast"? I want a SQL like this:
select * from zzz_teste where zzz_cod in (1, 2)


You can unwrap the JDBC class to progres own one, PGStatement. Then setting a low threshold can use a server side prepared statement. Not sure that will help.

This conversion is negatively impacting the performance of some SQL statements.. What is your proof for this?

@AdrianKlaver If a developer mistakenly uses setBigDecimal instead of setInt/setLong: https://i.ibb.co/wYD842G/test.png With the Oracle, this difference does not occur.

Do not use images, copy and paste the content as text as update to question text.
